# Tooltip content doesn't always wrap

Tags: angularjs

I have dynamically generated tooltip content that shows the name of the file on hover.

Occasionally the text will wrap: [image]

and other times, it will not: [image]

I have also noticed that this has nothing to do with the length of the name - sometimes shorter file names will refuse to wrap even though those with 10 extra characters have no problem.

Is anyone else having this issue? Thanks!

Comment: some code would be appreciated :-)

Comment: Try to use `word-break: break-all;` css.

Comment: @tracyak13: You are welcome ;) I posted my comment as an answer, so you can accept it if you want:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use `word-break: break-all;` css.